# What does data ... where mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, gadt

I saw this snippet at [the devlog of omegagb](http://www.mutantlemon.com/omegagb/devlog/):

```
data ExecutionAST result where
  Return :: result -> ExecutionAST result
  Bind :: (ExecutionAST oldres) -> (oldres -> ExecutionAST result) ->
          ExecutionAST result
  WriteRegister :: M_Register -> Word8 -> ExecutionAST ()
  ReadRegister :: M_Register -> ExecutionAST Word8
  WriteRegister2 :: M_Register2 -> Word16 -> ExecutionAST ()
  ReadRegister2 :: M_Register2 -> ExecutionAST Word16
  WriteMemory :: Word16 -> Word8 -> ExecutionAST ()
  ReadMemory :: Word16 -> ExecutionAST Word8
```

What does the `data ... where` mean? I thought the keyword `data` is used to define a new type.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It defines a new type, the syntax is called [generalized algebraic data type](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/GADT).

It is more general than the normal syntax. You can write any normal type definition (ADT) using GADTs:

```
data E a = A a | B Integer
```

can be written as:

```
data E a where
  A :: a -> E a
  B :: Integer -> E a
```

But you can also restrict what is on right hand side:

```
data E a where
  A :: a -> E a
  B :: Integer -> E a
  C :: Bool -> E Bool
```

which is not possible with a normal ADT declaration.

For more, check Haskell wiki or [this video](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2010/06/01-gadts-video.html).

---

The reason is type safety. `ExecutionAST t` is supposed to be type of statements returning `t`. If you write a normal ADT

```
data ExecutionAST result = Return result 
                         | WriteRegister M_Register Word8
                         | ReadRegister M_Register
                         | ReadMemory Word16
                         | WriteMemory Word16
                         | ...
```

then `ReadMemory 5` will be a polymorphic value of type `ExecutionAST t`, instead of monomorphic `ExecutionAST Word8`, and this will type check:

```
x :: M_Register2
x = ...

a = Bind (ReadMemory 1) (WriteRegister2 x)
```

That statement should read memory from location 1 and write to register `x`. However, reading from memory gives 8-bit words, and writing to `x` requires 16-bit words. By using a GADT, you can be sure this won't compile. Compile-time errors are better than run-time errors.

GADTs also include [existential types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_types). If you tried to write bind this way:

```
data ExecutionAST result = ... 
                           | Bind (ExecutionAST oldres)
                                  (oldres -> ExecutionAST result)
```

then it won't compile since "oldres" is not in scope, you have to write:

```
data ExecutionAST result = ...
                           | forall oldres. Bind (ExecutionAST oldres)
                                                 (oldres -> ExecutionAST result)
```

If you are confused, check the linked video for simpler, related example.

Comment: Can some one explain to me, why GADT is needed here?

Comment: @wliao: Added an explanation.

Comment: I find your explanation is better than the video clip. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Note that it is also possible to put class constraints:

```
data E a where
  A :: Eq b => b -> E b
```

Comment: And more importantly, unlike in regular `data` declarations, this actually causes the instance dictionary to be stored in the type, allowing you to recover it through pattern matching, just like with existential types.

Comment: @hammar I don't understand what your comment imply. I don't understand this wording (with my rephrasing) 'to recover the instance dictionary through pattern matching because it is stored in the type'. When I pattern match, I deconstruct according the shape of the structure, and I don't see how this translates to a "instance dictionary", and why it is different that it is store in the type. What should I read/learn to understand the sense of this ?